# How to separate Android layout for TV and phone/tablet?

Tags: android, android-tv

I have an android app that works on phone/tablet. I want to add support for Android TV.

Official documentation says to create a separate activity for TV.

Only difference between phone and TV is presentation layer (i.e. view), so I should only have to create new layouts, not the controller as well.

I created layouts that work for TV and use the same controller. Problem is that I cannot specify which layouts are for TV and which ones are for phones/tablets.

I cannot make assumptions about screen size and device type. Some phones have higher screen resolution than TVs and vice versa.

How can I provide different layouts for phone and TV?

If there is a better way to do this without writing (or copying) my existing java code I would accept that too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can I provide different layouts for phone and TV?

If this is an official Android TV environment, AFAIK `res/layout-television/` should work. See the legendary [Table 2](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources).

Comment: what about `UI mode` in android resources?

Comment: Awesome! I created layout, layout-land and layout-land-television with different layouts. layout-land is used on phone/tablet, layout-land-television on a TV. Same for styles. Works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A more reliable way to identify if it is a TV, or Phone could be.
It can even check if it is watch, appliance or other devices.

```
UiModeManager uiModeManager = (UiModeManager) getSystemService(UI_MODE_SERVICE);
if (uiModeManager.getCurrentModeType() == Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Running on a TV Device");
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "Running on a non-TV Device");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this boolean check to se if you are on a TV :

```
    context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("com.google.android.tv")
```